# Angular 15.7.2: How to use a navigationContextMenu or navigationMenu with different functionality in the same component

Tags: typescript, user-interface, angular-material

I am pretty new to Angular thats why I probably ask this question which seems simple but I can t find a solution. I have a navigationContextMenu in my app that I want to reuse in the same component but when clicking a menuitem the functionality should be different. The Code looks like this.

ts. file
@ViewChild('navigationMenu') navigationContextMenu!: MatMenu;

html.file
My new Button:
<button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialogTargetMenu($event, navigationContextMenu)"> Choose Startdialog 
The existing button:
<button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialogTargetMenu($event, navigationContextMenu)"> Add Connection 
<mat-menu #navigationMenu="matMenu" xPosition="after" yPosition="below">

The place where the functionality is implemented this should be another one:
<mat-option *ngFor="let dialog of getDialogPages()" (click)="connectDialogs(dialog.key)">{{ dialog.value }}

I tried to rename navigationContextMenu to navigationContextMenu1 and navigationmenu to navigationmenu1 but it doesn t work. What am I getting wrong and how can this easy thing be done?

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of an image.